# creating a tuple using loop, rather than specifying each element separately

Tags: python

I am trying to create a `tuple` as:

```
tuples = (i+1,
          db.entries[i].get("ENTRYTYPE"),
          db.entries[i].get("ID"),
          db.entries[i].get("title"),
          db.entries[i].get("author"),
          db.entries[i].get("journal"),
          db.entries[i].get("year")
          )
```

where db is a database, `i` is properly defined.

Now, the get("text") has ~40 different text. I can do it manually, and it is working. But is it possible to do it in some other way, e.g. loop like:

```
Entries = ["ENTRYTYPE", "ID", "title", "author" ...]
for entry in entries:
  tuples = (i+1, db.entries.get(entry)
```

Comment: Why not just use a list?

Comment: Actually, I will get some values empty. And I need to keep the order.

Comment: What? Please update your question with more information and some test data.

Comment: You can't have empty places in tuple.  You have to put `None` or something   other in empty places. And you can do the same with list.

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as `tuples = (i+1,) + tuple(db.entries.get(e) for e in Entries)`

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a tuple, try this:

```
tuples = tuple([i+1] + [db.entries.get(entry) for entry in entries])
```